# How can I hook into the wp_mail function used by BackWPup?

Tags: php, functions, hooks

I know this question is partially concerns a third-party plugin, BackWPup, which is off-topic, but in general, in terms of WordPress and PHP: is it possible to hook into the wp_mail function so can I append text to the plugin's PHP generated email?

The email is sent by BackWPUp, a WordPress database backup plugin, and the email contains a success or fail message about the backup file. In my case, the email will go to a general email support address, and may be received by someone who may not fully familiar with how to deal with the email. I need to be able to add more instructional and explanatory text to the email, preferably at the beginning of the email.

And I need to add that text by using an external php function, because if I modify the plugin, the changes will be overwritten when the plugin is updated; so I need to add the function to either in the theme's functions.php file, or make my own simple WordPress plugin.

The `wp_mail` function in the plugin that is used appears to be:

```
wp_mail(
$this->job['mailaddresslog'],
$subject,
file_get_contents( $this->logfile ),
$headers
);
```

is it possible to hook into the `$message`and add additional text? It has been replaced with `file_get_contents` in the function. Do I need to hook into `file_get_contents`?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

**Edit 7/28/19**

I added a check for the subject line, as all emails sent had the additional text appended. Now, only BackWPUp emails get the additional text.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wpse343761_filter_message' );
function wpse343761_filter_message( $atts ) {

    if ( stripos( $atts['subject'], 'BackWPup')) {

    if ( ! empty( $atts['message'] ) ) {
        $atts['message'] .= 'Your additional text';
    }
}
    return $atts;
}
```

New questions on modifying `message`: how can I use `strip_tags` on the `message` to convert the default html email to non-html email? Adding `strip_tags($atts['message']);` before the `return` doesn't do anything.

And, how can the "additional text message" be added to the beginning of the email? It's added to the end right now.

Comment: how you know they use php mail() function.

Comment: I don't know if Swiftmailer uses phpmail.

Comment: The plugin authors may be able to tell you

Comment: Can you post the contents of the email that is received by the user??

Comment: I searched the plugin files and it uses phpmailer.

Comment: if you found wp_mail() function then you can use hook or filter to change you body content.

Comment: @Bhautik Actually, I guess the plugin uses https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ according to their support forum. So that can be hooked into?

Comment: @ChristopherJones I found the function in use and edited my question; the email contents is from `file_get_contents`; it's the site URL, part of the log, etc. Can that be hooked into to add my own text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of the [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) function, there's a filter right near the top:

```
$atts = apply_filters( 
    'wp_mail', 
    compact( 'to', 'subject', 'message', 'headers', 'attachments' )
);
// Expanded for clarity.
```

> (Aside: [`compact()`](https://php.net/compact) is a PHP function that creates an array from a set of arguments. In this case, it's making an array of the `$to`, `$subject`, `$message`, `$headers`, and `$attachments` parameters passed to `wp_mail()`.)

...and then a little further on:

```
if ( isset( $atts['subject'] ) ) {
    $subject = $atts['subject'];
}
```

So yes, you *can* filter the message.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wpse343761_filter_message' );
function wpse343761_filter_message( $atts ) {
    if ( ! empty( $atts['message'] ) ) {
        // If there's already a message, add to it.
        $atts['message'] .= 'Your additional text';
    } else {
        // If there's not a message set yet, set one.
        $atts['message'] = 'Your desired message';
    }
    return $atts;
}
```

**Note:** This code is untested.

**Edit**: In response to your update *And, how can the "additional text message" be added to the beginning of the email?*:

Change this line:

```
$atts['message'] .= 'Your additional text';
```

to:

```
$atts['message'] = 'Your additional text' . $atts['message'];
```

And to your `strip_tags()` usage question, you can do this:

```
$atts['message'] = strip_tags( $atts['message'] );
```

on the line before you `return`. (You can't just use `strip_tags( $atts['message'] )` because that doesn't assign the stripped string to anything.)

Comment: Thanks, that works. I added a check for the subject line, since all admin emails were getting the additional text. Do you know how I can use strip_tags to convert the html email to plain text? I edited my question.

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: Thanks! Works great.